# Creating an HMAC with an existing password hash and salt

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, gitkit

For migration reasons I need to take an existing password & salt and place it into Firebase. I'm uploading accounts into Firebase using the google identity kit. This kit allows me to create users and requires a SHA-1 password salted.

```
var user1 = {
localId: userId,
email: email,
salt: new Buffer('salt-1'),
  passwordHash: crypto.createHmac('SHA1', this.hashKey).update('a password' + 'salt-1').digest()
};
```

Above is what would be uploaded to the server. Is there any way to crypto.createHmac with an existing SHA-1 hash and salt? I've tried just replacing the passwordHash and salt with the values, but they need to be encoded the same way createHmac encodes them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [HMAC Implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code#Implementation).

The key HMAC code is:

```
hash(o_key_pad ∥ hash(i_key_pad ∥ message))
```

So it seems the answer is no since the padded key needs to be concatenated with the message.

Comment: After realizing that I was handling HMACs and not regular SHA-1s, I guess my question has changed to - 'How do I place existing salted SHA-1 keys into firebase using gitkit'.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the existing HMAC key as the `signerKey` in the Google Identity Toolkit UploadAccounts API request: https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/reference/relyingparty/uploadAccount